# How to activate console mode?

Tags: macos, arcade, mame

I'd like to be able to change the mode from "Arcade" to "Console" (that enables things like training mode on certain fighting games, etc.).

Is there a way to do this on MAME OS X? There's no option in the preferences window, and if you enter the settings of the emulator (<kbd>F2</kbd>) you can change some of the settings of the game but not enable console mode.

I've also read that it has to do with the BIOS it's running. I donwloaded a neogeo.zip (without it games don't even run)... but I don't know how to force MAME OS X to run a particular bios either (I've read that unibios makes the trick but I'm clueless about how to make it work).

Thoughts?

Comment: For which games in particular? Most games emulated by MAME don't have any such option.

Comment: I'm sure the games I'm trying to play support console mode. I know it because using plain MAME (emulated with wine) or NeoGeoRage, you can enable it.

Answer (score 2):

First, I suppose you talk of neogeo games...

Specify the bios in the command line with -bios.

uni-bios has the aes/console switch

Ex:
mame garoup -bios uni-bios_2_3

Comment: Yes, that works... when you use the Windows mame version. Here I'm dealing with Mame OS X though.

Comment: Did you try the sdl version ? Also give a try to mess, I heard you can activate console version.

Comment: Here is a link for mac osx mame version: http://www.tweaking4all.com/software/games/macos-x-run-mame-mavericks-10-9/